# Angular 2 - Overriding Components in Testing

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I have a problem in Angular 2 unit testing. I want to mock a component or override a component when testing. How do I do this?

I have sample codes below

**a.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'a-component',
  templateUrl: `<b-component>`
})
export class AComponent {
  @ViewChild(BComponent) bcomp: BComponent;
  testFunction(){
    if(bcomp.num > 1){
      ----------> Put Code Here
    } else{
      ----------> Put Code Here
    }
  }
}
```

**b.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'b-component',
  templateUrl: `some code`
})
export class BComponent {
  public num: number;
```

I want to mock **b.component.ts** because **a.component.ts** uses the num for it's logic just as the one in testFunction() in **a.component.ts**. Please help.